# Increasing real valued function whose image set is connected

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Let $S = [0,1) \cup [2,3]$ and $f\colon S \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be such that $f(S)$ is connected . Which of the following are true:

a) $f$ is discontinuous exactly at one point.

b) $f$ is discontinuous exactly at two points.

c) $f$ is discontinuous at infinite many points.

d) $f$ is continous.

I think $f$ is continuous . We need to show that $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) = f(a)$ for any $a \in S$. Since $f(x)$ is increasing, $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) \leq f(a)$. Suppose $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) < f(a)$. Then there is $l$ such that $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) < l <f(a)$, which contradicts connectedness of $f(S)$. Similarly we can show that $\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) = f(a)$.

I would be thankful if anyone would check my solution and correct me if there are any errors.

Comment: is $f$ increasing as in the title? If so, put it in.

Comment: yes, $f$ is inceasing, I have also used

Comment: Your proof is not complete because it seems to me you're using that $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)$ exists.  How do you know it exists for all $a$?  What if it is $\pm\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is pretty good but it has a couple of loose ends you should tie up.  First, you assume $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^{+}}f(x)$ exists.  It does, but you need to show it.  One way would be to let $x_n$ be any sequence such that $x_n\to a$ and $x_n$ is monotone decreasing.  Then $\langle f(x_n)\rangle$ is monotonically decreasing and is bounded below by $f(0)$.  Therefore $\langle f(x_n)\rangle$ converges by the monotone convergence theorem.  Thus you can conclude the continuous limit converges.

Next you should show why $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^{+}}f(x)<\ell<f(a)$ implies $f(S)$ is not connected.  You can say for example that if $A=f(S)\cap(-\infty,\ell]$ and $B=f(S)\cap[\ell,\infty)$ then $S=A\cup B$ a disjoint union of closed sets in $f(S)$ which is impossible if $f(S)$ is connected.

Comment: How can we show that $\ell \notin f(S)$? Please explain@Gregory Grant

Comment: @Anupam It's because the limit of $f(x)$ for $x\rightarrow a$ from the right is strictly less than $\ell$.  Keep in mind $f$ is monotone.  Think of what the graph of $f$ must look like at $x=a$.  The limit exists from the right and from the left, but the limit from the left is strictly less than the limit from the right.  So the graph must have a gap of size $f(a)-\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)$ and $\ell$ was chosen to be in that gap.

Comment: @Gregory Grant when $x \to a^+$ then $x$ approaches to $a$ from the right of $a.$ But since $f$ is increasing so for any of those $x$ we should have $f(x) \geq f(a).$ Thus $\lim\limits_{x \to a^+} f(x) \geq f(a).$ Similarly $\lim\limits_{x \to a^-} f(x) \leq f(a).$ If $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists so the result follows i.e. $f$ is continuous at $a.$ Am I missing something?