# Strictly increasing function $f$ such that $f(S)$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $S=[0,1)\cup[2,3]$ and $f:S \to \Bbb R$ be a strictly increasing map such that $f(S)$ is connected.Can i say that $f$ must be continuous ? According to me $f$ being monotone so only jump discontinuity and since image is connected so no jump discontinuity and hence continuous. Am i right?

Comment: You are right. You can even say that $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x) = f(2)$.

Comment: You should write it rigorously.

Comment: It's already [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1635426/increasing-real-valued-function-whose-image-set-is-connected)